# Can we force perl always use three argument form of open when running from command line?

Tags: perl, security

Running `perl` one-liners from command line has [security implications](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170013/security-implications-of-running-perl-ne/170107#170107).

The problem is that options `-n/-p` trigger the diamond operator `<>`, which use two arguments form of `open`, so with files name contain special characters, `perl` doesn't work as expected:

```
$ perl -pe '' 'uname|'
Linux
```

Or more dangerous when files name starting with `>`, like `>file`. In this case, file will be truncated.

For work around with this issue, we can:

- Use [ARGV::readonly](http://search.cpan.org/~davidnico/ARGV-readonly-0.01/lib/ARGV/readonly.pm) module from CPAN.
- Implement feature like `ARGV::readonly` module by ourself:

---

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{$_.="\0" for @ARGV} ...' ./*
```

---

- Use `-i` option, as `perl` will check for file existed before processing it.
- Use `-T` option to enable taint mode.

I think all solutions can fix this issue, but also have their side effects. If we can force `perl` always use thee argument form of `open`, it'll be a better solution.

I wonder can we do it, force `perl` always use thee argument form of `open`?

**Note**

The question only apply for the case when running `perl` one liners from command line, because (of course) we can always use three argument form of `open` in Perl script.

Comment: I understand your point, but I don't see how the output of `perl -pe '' 'uname|'` isn't what people would expect, and would have thought the greater danger is `perl -pe"1" ">myfile"`. I think all command-line input files should be opened using three-parameter form with the second parameter always set to `<`.

Comment: @Borodin: `'uname|'` is a valid file name, instead of open it, command `uname` is executed and pipe to `perl`. And imaging that the command can be `rm -rf $HOME`. Yes, except for `-i` option, when you want to edit file in-place. You can read the link I gave in my question for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my previous answer, I hypothesized that `ARGV` filehandle magic emulated the 2-argument open but didn't actually go through Perl's builtin `open` function. So I investigated it some more and I think I came up with an actual solution to this problem.

The function [`Perl_nextargv`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/doio.c#L804) in [`doio.c`](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/perl-5.22.0/doio.c) is where perl performs I/O around the `ARGV` filehandle.

Inside that function's `while` loop, there are two kinds of calls to open filehandles. When `LIKELY(PL_inplace)` is true (i.e., when perl is run with the `-i` switch), the call is `do_open_raw`. When `LIKELY(PL_inplace)` is false, the call is to `do_open6`. The latter call is capable of opening pipes to external commands, which is in general what the OP does not want.

So here's the solution: in the source file `doio.c`, replace those `do_open6` call(s) in `Perl_nextargv` with `do_open_raw` and rebuild `perl` from source. For perl-5.22.0, the original code looks like

```
    if (LIKELY(!PL_inplace)) {
        if (nomagicopen
                ? do_open6(gv, "<", 1, NULL, &GvSV(gv), 1)
                : do_open6(gv, PL_oldname, oldlen, NULL, NULL, 0)
           ) {
            return IoIFP(GvIOp(gv));
        }
    }
```

and the altered code looks like

```
    if (LIKELY(!PL_inplace)) {
        if (do_open_raw(gv, PL_oldname, oldlen, O_RDONLY, 0)) {
            return IoIFP(GvIOp(gv));
        }
    }
```

(the `nomagicopen` parameter is true when you use [the new `<<>>` syntax from perl 5.22.0](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perlop.pod#I-O-Operators). I guess we could just set it to `true` at the top of the function and not have to change anything else, but the change above is a general solution for older perl's).

Sample output:

```
$ original-perl -pe '' a b c 'date|'
Can't open a: No such file or directory
Can't open b: No such file or directory.
Can't open c: No such file or directory.
Mon Sep 21 18:41:37 PDT 2015

$ modified-perl -pe '' a b c 'date|'
Can't open a: No such file or directory.
Can't open b: No such file or directory.
Can't open c: No such file or directory.
Can't open date|: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: +1 for hacking `perl` source. I wonder why `perl` still used two arguments form? Does changing `<>` behave like `<<>>` break backward compatible?

Comment: It's Perl, so yeah, there are probably scripts out there that depend on this behavior. Maybe someday we will have `-N` and `-P` switches like `-n` and `-p` that wrap the script in `while(<<>>) { ... }`.

Answer (score 4):

You probably only want to do this for one-liners (using the `-e` switch), so you'll want to customize `ARGV::readonly` for that purpose.

```
package Sanitize::ARGV;
if ($0 eq '-e') {
    @ARGV = map {  # from ARGV::readonly
        s/^(\s+)/.\/$1/;
        s/^/< /;
        $_.qq/\0/;
    } @ARGV;
}
1;
```

To force this package to be used system-wide, you can use an alias as Patrick J.S. suggests

```
alias perl='perl -MSanitize::ARGV'
```

or set a system-wide `PERL5OPT` variable

```
PERL5OPT="-MSanitize::ARGV"
```

And if you want to be more paranoid, hide your system perl (rename it to something unintelligible) and replace it with a wrapper

```
#!/bin/bash
THE_REAL_PERL=/usr/bin/glorbqweroinuerqwer
$THE_REAL_PERL -MSanitize::ARGV "$@"
```

The shell wrapper will still respect any user customizations to `PERL5OPT`

---

In the general case, you can use the `CORE::GLOBAL` mechanism to override the builtin `open` function, e.g.

```
package SafeOpen;
use Carp;
BEGIN {
    *CORE::GLOBAL::open = sub (*;$@) {
        goto &CORE::open if @_ > 2;
        Carp::cluck("OH MY GOD USING THE TWO-ARG open ARE YOU LIKE INSANE?");
        return CORE::open($_[0], '<', $_[1] // $_[0]);
    };
}
1;
```

and when this module is in use you will catch anyone in the act of using a 2-arg `open` call. Unfortunately, I think the mechanism of the `ARGV` filehandle magic bypasses this, so it still doesn't help with goofy filenames on the command line in a one-liner.

Comment: Yes, I know the ways to sanity check `@ARGV`. My question is about is there anyway to force `perl` to use three argument open?

Comment: You can set up a `CORE::GLOBAL::open` sub (and I tried it to see if it would solve your problem), but I think the `ARGV` mechanism magic bypasses it.

Comment: Well, that's what I mentioned in my question. And I guess set up `CORE::GLOBAL::open` have no effects. Since when the `-n` and `-p` switch trigger the diamond operator `<>`, which use the two arguments form of `open`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ARGV::readonly` in combination with `alias`:

```
alias perl='perl -MARGV::readonly'
```

Or just educate the people that are typing the "bad" oneliners.

Comment: Or you could add `-MARGV::readonly` to the `PERL5OPT` environment variable